# Transfer variable between Python module

Tags: python, function, variables, python-2.7

For example, I have a file called "gui.py", which uses a module, which is called "pytime.py".
They are in the same directory.

The module (time.py) code has two functions: settime() and readtime()

gui.py code looks like:

```
import pytime
pytime.settime(16,40) #set hour to 16:40
```

Now, I want that the other function in the pytime module (readtime()) could access the hour. 
I tried "global" but it didn't helped, and also googled a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: What? What does `pytime.settime` actually *do*? What does it change?

Comment: It adds variable called time, which include the time. And the readtime() should read this variable

Comment: What do you mean *"adds variable"*? Could you just show a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than describing it?

Comment: Im really sorry if i wasn't clear enough. Engljsh is not my first language as you can see :( . I meant that it is set new variable, that readtime() should read.

Comment: It is still not clear what you mean *"set new variable"*. What variable, in what scope (just inside the function? Module-level `global`), of what type? This isn't a problem of English language proficiency; please just **show us the code**, this will be much more explicit then any attempted description.

Answer (score 1):

if you want shared state between the functions, the best way to do this would probably be a class:

```
# pytime.py
class PyTime(object):

    def __init__(self, hour=0, minute=0):
        self._hour = hour
        self._minute = minute

    def set_time(self, hour=None, minute=None):
        if hour is not None:
            self._hour = hour
        if minute is not None:
            self._minute = minute

    def read_time(self):
        return self._hour, self._minute

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0._hour:02d}:{0._minute:02d}".format(self)

    @property
    def hour(self):
        return self._hour

    @property
    def minute(self):
        return self._minute
```

In use:

```
>>> timer = PyTime()
>>> timer.set_time(16, 40)
>>> timer.read_time()
(16, 40)
>>> timer.hour
16
>>> str(timer)
'16.40'
 >>> timer.set_time(minute=30)
>>> str(timer)
'16:30'
>>> timer.hour = 15

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>
    timer.hour = 15
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Note this last result - as I define a property getter for `hour` but no setter, `hour` is immutable (although a determined user can access `_hour` directly).

Comment: I would have also suggested this approach. Always try to use class for this type of issues.

Comment: Im trying it right now. Ill be back and say if it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could **pass** in the variable into the function as such:

**`pytime.py`:**

```
def settime(hour, minute):
        return str(hour)+':'+str(minute)

def readtime(hour):
        print 'This is the hour: {0}'.format(hour)
```

**`gui.py`:**

```
import pytime
hour = pytime.settime(16, 40)
pytime.readtime(hour)
```

This runs as:

```
bash-3.2$ python gui.py
This is the hour: 16:40
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Thankes for your answer! But, the problem is that i call readtime() a lot of times in the program and it would be anoyying to set the 'hour' variable each time I call it. I need a way that readtime() will read it automaticlly. Anyway, thanks!